# How to fix dll that do not load in vscode but loaded in IDLE python

Tags: python, matlab, visual-studio-code, spyder

With **same python version** (3.6.2 64bit) I tried same code that **work in IDLE** but it do **not work in vscode** (or spyder or Matlab when they call  same python)

I tested it In an other computer even with win7 (my win is 10)
But I should say both computers have multi versions of python

```
 from openseespy.opensees import *
```

And I get the following error -

> DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .../pushover-concentrated.py", line 3, in <module>
    import openseespy.opensees as op
    packages\openseespy\opensees\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from openseespy.opensees.winpy36.opensees import *
```

> (this is part of **openseespy** package code that recognize os)

```
    ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in  _run_code

    exec(code, run_globals)
     ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code

mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
    ..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
     pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

Package link - https://openseespydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That traceback is incomplete because it lacks the exception being raised.

Comment: traceback added

Comment: Unfortunately that's still not the complete traceback as you're missing the exception type, etc. Another way to try and figure this out is if you printed out what `sys.path` is and see if there's any difference.